# Check that the username already exists in AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-forms

I've started to work with Django after a lot of PHP work.
I got used to AJAX with PHP and it's working well. But I was doing procedural PHP so now in Django, I am a bit lost.

My first AJAX use case is very simple. I am doing a register page with a form and I would like to check in AJAX if the username the user filled in is available or not.
I did it in Python, but now, I would like to do it in AJAX but I really don't know how to do it. Though the web, I found several tutorials but no one is the same as the others, and I don't know how to do it regarding my own code.

If you can guide me, that would be great.

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from membres.models import UserProfile, UserProfilePublic, UserProfilePrivate
from membres.forms import RegisterForm

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.is_ajax():
            if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                return "exists"

        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username'].strip()
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            slug = slugify(username)

            user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
            profile = UserProfile(user= user, slug= slug)
            profile.save()
            profile_public = UserProfilePublic(user= user)
            profile_public.save()
            profile_private = UserProfilePrivate(user= user)
            profile_private.save()

            form_validated = True

    else:
        form = RegisterForm()

    return render(request, 'membres/register.html', locals())
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(min_length=5, max_length=30, required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=75, required=True)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, required=True)
    password_check = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, required=True)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(RegisterForm, self).clean()
        username = cleaned_data.get('username')
        email = cleaned_data.get('email')
        password = cleaned_data.get('password')
        password_check = cleaned_data.get('password_check')

        # Username
        if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            msg = "Cet utilisateur existe déjà"
            self.add_error('username', msg)

        # Password
        if password_check != password:
            msg = "Le mot de passe et sa confirmation doivent être identiques"
            self.add_error('password_check', msg)

        return cleaned_data
```

register.html template:

```
blur: function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        var length = value.length;
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var label = $("label[for='"+id+"']");
        if($(this).parent().hasClass("field-mandatory")) {
            if(!value) {
                $("label[for='"+id+"']").append(checkStartInvalid + "Ne peut être vide" + checkEnd);
            } else {
                if(id == 'id_username') {
                    if(length < 5 || length > 30) {
                        label.append(checkStartInvalid + "Nombre de caractères compris entre 5 et 30" + checkEnd);
                    } else {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '',
                            data: 'username='+value,
                            type: 'POST',
                            success: function(data){
                                console.log(data);
                            }
                        });
                        label.append(checkValid);
                    }
                }
```

As you can see in views.py I tried, but I get an error in the console: "NetworkError: 403 FORBIDDEN - ..."

What's the best practice?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should include CSRF token in your request (or decorate your `register` method with csrf_exempt - what I don't recommend).

Just take a look to this example
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax

---

As [Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman) has mentioned in comments, you should use GET method for your purposes. It's correct from semantic view-point of HTTP methods.
Read more [Here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)

Comment: Although since this is a simple check, rather than actually saving data, OP could use a GET request which doesn't require a CSRF token.

Comment: Sure. You're right.
Because this request doesn't change the state of server, OP must use GET method.

Comment: Hi, thanks for both answer, but no matter the solution, now I'm getting a 500 error...
Any idea where it could be?

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
  $.ajax({
     csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value,

                        url: '',
                        data: 'username='+value,
                        type: 'POST',
                        success: function(data){
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: here is same example http://www.djangotutsme.com/question/how-to-send-ajax-in-django-rendering-json/